# Is my Mercedes spying on me?

Tags: mercedes-benz, telematics

I have a Mercedes E450 and it routinely seems to be tracking geolocation data. For example, on the dash there is message to the effect of "last address visited" and showing that address as though it is carefully noting every place I visit. My concern is that this information could be getting relayed somewhere else.

I notice Mercedes has issued the following privacy notice:

> Even if you have not activated Mercedes me connect services, the
> vehicle may collect and transmit geolocation information and driver
> behavior information in a collision or potential emergency. See the
> vehicle’s Operator’s Manual for more information. Geolocation
> information may also be accessed without activation of Mercedes me
> connect services by third-party services providers in accordance with
> your agreements with them.

So, this statement has multiple ambiguities. For example, what is a 'potential emergency'?

The bottom line here is I want to know if the car is routinely sending my location data to Mercedes or anybody else. I am hoping for actual knowledge, not just some readers opinion about a privacy statement, because obvious what is in the privacy statement is written by a bunch of lawyers who may know little about how car data is actually treated.

Comment: I don't have an answer on this, I will say that if you own a smartphone then it's going to be giving more information about you than a car ever could.

Comment: @GdD yeah that's absolutely true.  People fussing about government trackers invariably do so with a cell phone within 100' of them.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, your car is (to use your word) spying on you.  In reality it's doing what you have agreed to let it do, which is to communicate your location and other information back to MB and they are doing with it what they say in the agreement.

Don't like it?  Probably nothing you can do but sell the thing and get a car that doesn't have a "phone home" feature.

This is what you get with a modern "connected" vehicle.  I suppose there are ways to disable the mobile network connection unit in the car but that may have the effect is disabling other features and setting diagnostic codes.